# Why is my laptop still charging when the battery is not plugged in?

Tags: power-supply, battery

My Advent 5431 laptop is dual booting windows 7 and ubuntu and has a U40-3S3700-B1Y1 battery pack. It says that it is always charging even when the charger is unplugged. Why would this be? When I unplug the power cord it continues to say that it is plugged in and charging but the battery life goes down until it powers off without a warning.

Comment: in both operating systems the same behavior?

Comment: yes @StampedeXV

Comment: Seems like your charging circuit firmware went insane. Yay!

Comment: Is your power brick still connected to the laptop? Just unplugged from the wall socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your battery may be broken and supplies power with a higher voltage than what it is designed for. I would suggest you measure your battery and see if it delivers the correct voltage. The other (more likely) scenario is that you got some fried electronics in your laptop that incorrectly indicates charging (if the same behavior is observed in both Windows and Ubuntu).

Comment: okay, so is there anyway to fix it and is it the battery thats broken or the laptop?

Comment: your best bet would be to get the battery examined by a qualified person and/or try a replacement battery first. It is however more likely that your electronics on your laptop is broken. In Linux you can ask the status for your battery via the terminal via your proc filesystem (google how to).

Comment: uhm I asked this in August but thanks for the help anyway, the battery expanded and so I got a new battery which also expanded and did the same thing. I'm quite worried about it actually. I've taken the battery out and now I use my laptop without one which can be annoying but it's better than battery juice exploding in my face I suppose...

Comment: If your battery is expanding it is overcharging without doubt. Your charger is probably supplying a higher voltage than what it should. It *might* already have destroyed some components in your computer as well - check and/or replace it *NOW*

Answer (score 0):

If it is for both OS the same (your comment at the question) I would check firmware.

This means: Is there a new BIOS for your Laptop available? Install it. Maybe that already fixes your problem.